# Сохранить файл через браузер

Tags: node.js

Есть ссылка на удаленный ресурс, при переходе по этой ссылке открывается стандартные браузерный плеер для воспроизведения mp3. Как сделать так чтобы файл не открывался а сохранялся пользователю а не на сервере в случае использования fs?

вот мой код

```
app.post('/download', function (req, res) {

    var link = req.body.link;
    var title = req.body.title;

    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'+ title +'".mp3');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
    res.redirect(link);
```

еще пробовал вот так

```
app.post('/download', function (req, res) {

    var link = req.body.link;
    var title = req.body.title;

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Description': 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
        'Expires': '0',
        'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'public',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="'+ title +'".mp3',
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': 1000000000
    });
});
```

файл скачивается но с нулевым размером

Comment: Добавить правильный заголовок Content-Disposition

Comment: пробовал добавлять 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="'+ title +'".mp3',, файл скачивается, но имеет нулевой размер

Comment: Куда вы его добавили. Покажите код

Comment: В пост, пожалуйста. Код в комментариях невозможно читать

Comment: добавил код в пост

Comment: Впрочем. Этот заголовок должен быть не в редиректе, а там где отдаётся собственно файл

Comment: у меня нет доступа к серверу отдающему файл, если открыть ссылку https://cs9-8v4.userapi.com/p15/a20dc5b4becc27.mp3?extra=tfe63f-t3Uacf8c1fe7GrbqoSkb09PJX3p0JqwUbnC0Q4MrFXA4kdQe-H_b5hPUhd823XfuWveS5pWvtfCNtYQTHr7sFTDPwibibYLbb6QaVDnnF_hzL8OWymy00sfDqrT2y в браузере, то там есть кнопочка "скачать" как то же это работает

Comment: Не открывается.

Comment: У меня во всех браузерах открывается,

Comment: Очевидно это персональная ссылка

Comment: нет, это публичная ссылка, у моих коллег она тоже открывается, в посте описал решение своего вопроса

Comment: Очевидно не публичная. Возможно она доступна для какой-то группы в которой вы все состоите. Впрочем это уже оффтопик

Comment: @VitaliyAndryushov лучше не добавлять ответ на свой вопрос, в тело самого вопроса. Просто оформите как ответ.

Comment: @AlexeyTen это ссылка на песню в ВК как она может быть не публичной?

Answer (score 1):

Решение вопроса:

```
var request = require('request');
app.post('/download', function (req, res) {
    var link = req.body.link;
    var title = req.body.title;

    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ title +".mp3");
    request(link).pipe(res);
});
```